# TypeError: Cannot read property 'FACEBOOK' of undefined in expo React native for Android

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

I am creating an Image share option in expo(only for android in react native) using the [react-native-share](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-share) library, but i am getting the following error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'FACEBOOK' of undefined`

My React Native code

```
import Share from 'react-native-share';

const baseImage = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA ......"; // base64image

const myCustomShare = async()=> {
  const shareOptions = {
      url: baseImage
  };
  try {
      const shareResponse = await Share.open(shareOptions)
  } catch(error) {
      console.log(error)
  }
}
```

I have already tried the following steps to resolve this issue but still i am getting the same error

1. npm install react-native-share
2. react-native link react-native-share

Comment: Based of package document the title in options is not optional. https://react-native-share.github.io/react-native-share/docs/share-open#supported-options . Add sample title and test it agail

Comment: @Majidlotfinia if I am adding title then only i am able share title not image. I have tries but only title is sharable

Comment: Are you sure the base64 string of the image is valid?

Comment: yes the base64 file i am using is correct, here I have not added the whole string because it's too large,
I was able to share the same base64 using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68435788/whatsapp-share-using-expo-sharing-library-in-androidreact-native

but I am facing some different issue now, can you check once if you can help me in that issue

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's some issue integrating the module correctly in your project. Please following the next steps:

step 01: yarn add react-native-share or npm install react-native-share

step 02: npx pod-install or cd ios && pod install. (You can skip this step, if you are using this on Android).